# Как конвертирова дату с месяцев в sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

есть строка с датой в виде: "Май 2020"
Как преобразовать эту строку к виду: "2020-05-01"??

Answer (score 0):

```
select convert(date,'01 '+'Май 2020',106)
```